# Redux thunk. reading data from local

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-redux

I would like to read the data from customData.json, through the code below but here it requires a url, although i would like to read it locally instead, is it possible to do this?

```
var customData = require('./customData.json');
export function fetchQuestions() {
  return dispatch => {
    fetch(customData, {
      method: 'get',
      headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
      }
    })
    .then(payload => payload.json())
    .then(payload => payload.results)
    .then(payload =>
      dispatch({
        type: 'FETCH_QUESTIONS',
        payload: payload
      })
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Locally, do you mean like from localStorage?

Comment: yeah thats what i mean, basically want ./customData.json to be fetched

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to read a JSON from localStorage instead of making a network request every time, it's pretty simple, there's nothing async involved. Assuming you've put it into `localStorage.customData`:

```js
export function fetchQuestions() {
  return dispatch => {
    const payload = JSON.parse(localStorage.customData);
    dispatch({
      type: 'FETCH_QUESTIONS',
      payload: payload.results,
    });
  }
}
```

Though, unless you're doing something else with it, it would be nicer to save the `.results` property only onto the disk, rather than the whole payload, since you're not using the rest of it.

Comment: cant find variable localstorage?

Comment: thank you very much! worked after - const payload = customData;